# Calendar month navigation in Ajax only working once

Tags: ajax, calendar

In Wordpress, I'm trying to code a calendar with Ajax to refresh when changing month. My problem : i can only change month once, after that, seems like nothing happens when I click the link to change month.

You can see it here : https://www.bons-plans-voyage-new-york.com/backend/calendrier/

My code :

```
function calendar_enqueue_scripts()
{
    if(!is_admin())
    {
        if(is_home() || is_page("calendrier"))
        {
            wp_deregister_script('jquery');
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);
            wp_enqueue_script('calendrier', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/calendrier.js', array('jquery') );


            wp_localize_script('calendrier', 'ajax_object', array(
                'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('my_nonce')
            ));

        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'calendar_enqueue_scripts');


function my_action()
{
    if ( isset( $_POST['year']) &&  isset($_POST['month'])  )
    {
        check_ajax_referer( 'my_nonce', 'nonce' );  // This function will die if nonce is not correct.
        $calendrier = get_html_calendar($_POST['year'],$_POST['month']);
        echo $calendrier;
        exit();
    } 
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );



function get_html_calendar($year = '',$month = '')
{
    // some stuff to generate calendar for given month & year

    $output = '';
    $output .= '<div id="calender_section" class="cf">';
    $output .= '<h2>';
    $output .= '<a year="'.date("Y",strtotime($date.' - 1 Month')).'" month="'.date("m",strtotime($date.' - 1 Month')).'">&lt;&lt;</a>';
    $output .= '<select name="month_dropdown" class="month_dropdown dropdown">'.getAllMonths($dateMonth).'</select>';
    $output .= '<select name="year_dropdown" class="year_dropdown dropdown">'.getYearList($dateYear).'</select>';
    $output .= '<a year="'.date("Y",strtotime($date.' + 1 Month')).'" month="'.date("m",strtotime($date.' + 1 Month')).'">&gt;&gt;</a>';
    $output .= '</h2>';

    // ... etc
    return $output;
}
```

And my calendrier.js :

```
(function($)
{   
    function ajax_refreshCalendar(target_div, year, month)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url : ajax_object.ajax_url, // Note that 'ajax_object' is from the wp_localize_script() call.
            type : 'post',
            data :
            {
                action : 'my_action',  // Note that this is part of the add_action() call.
                nonce : ajax_object.nonce,  // Note that 'aj_demo_nonce' is from the wp_localize_script() call.
                year : year,
                month : month,
            },
            success : function( response )
            {
                console.log("success");
                console.log(response);
                $("#"+target_div).html(response);
            }
        }).fail(function (response)
        {
            // This stuff only happens if things fail miserably.
            console.log("fail");
            console.log(response);
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        // Detect clics
        $("#calender_section a").on('click', function(e)
        {
            console.log("clic");

            // Prevent them from actually visiting the URL when clicking.
            e.preventDefault();

            var year = $(this).attr('year');
            var month = $(this).attr('month');
            var target_div = 'calendrier_wrapper';

            ajax_refreshCalendar(target_div, year, month);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

What am I missing ?
** edit : weirder, I got different results depending on wheter i'm logged in or not. I'm lost here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event target (`#calender_section a`) is replaced after refreshing the calendar. Because of the replacing, the event listener isn't applied to the target anymore. You have to apply the event listener to a parent element which doesn't get replaced (here it is `#calendrier_wrapper`) and use the selector parameter of `on` (see http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#calendrier_wrapper").on('click', '#calender_section a', function(e) {
    ...
});
```